# Python - vectorized function for calculating pairwise Pearson correlation coefficient

Tags: python, performance, correlation, pearson

I want to calculate correlation coefficient between the rows of the matrix X (N x k). Applying numpy.corrcoef(X) on a big matrix X is not efficient and it is slowing down my code so would like to make it faster.

Can somebody help me how can I achieve it? Vectorization? Any other function which is known that works fast with big N?

Answer (score 1):

It is already implemented. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html